# Returning a specific string from a JSON into separate variables | With Python

Tags: python, json

I am currently using a roblox API which returns some very LARGE json response but I am only looking for a specific data inside, the data I need looks something like this.

```
gameinstanceId=f4beb4fc-82d1-4573-82f1-dd94c13a94eb
```

I am only for the data after the "=" and save all the ones it finds into separate variables, I just need to find ALL of them basically.
I don't know how to get around doing this, I thought of using substrings but again I have no idea on how to do it.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood right, I think the regular expressions package (re) is your friend here. The following will return all instances found in a long string.

PS building regular expressions (regexes) can be tedious and I always forget the notation, so I always go to https://pythex.org/ to build my expressions.

```py
import re

longstring = 'gameinstanceId=f4beb4fc-82d1-4573-82f1-dd94c13a94eb\ngameinstanceId=f4beb4fc-82d1-4573-82f1-dd94c13a94eb\n'
re.findall(r'gameinstanceId=([\w-]*)', longstring)
```

This code returns a list with all matches:

```py
['f4beb4fc-82d1-4573-82f1-dd94c13a94eb',
 'f4beb4fc-82d1-4573-82f1-dd94c13a94eb']
```

With further feedback and a URL, this approach is probably what you want:

```py
import requests

resp = requests.get('https://rankbotddtgrcm.glitch.me/gameInstances?Place=2679871702')

re.findall(r'gameInstanceId=([\w-]*)', resp.text)
```

Comment: This will work perfectly, only problem is... Can I do this while it ```requests.get``` it? Edit: I will try this now.

Comment: Hmm I don't understand your question. Is this the response from a requests.get? Or you want to do this before using it in a requests.get? Or something else?

Comment: I am trying to request.get the JSON then trying to find ALL gameinstanceIds then put them into separate variables.

Comment: Ah I see, so the object you get returned from the request.get is probably a dictionary? (JSON is not a python data type). It would help if you posted an example of what it is you are trying to parse. Your original question did not make that very clear.

Comment: Here is a test link - https://rankbotddtgrcm.glitch.me/gameInstances?Place=2679871702

That shows the type of data I am trying to sort.

Comment: This is still not working, is there a way to store EVERY gameinstanceId in a array?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. This doesn't catch all of them? Can you give an example?

Comment: Honestly apologies, I didn't set ```re.findall``` line as a variable and was just trying to print ```resp.text``` - other than that works perfectly! Thank you good sir!

Answer (score 0):

I use list comprehensions for this sort of thing:

```
mylist = [line.split("=",1)[1] for line in resp.text.splitlines() if line.startswith("gameinstanceId=")]
```

I typed this in on the fly, but it should be close.

Comment: I need the list to be from a http response.

Comment: I used `resp` from the answer by @William